# .fadeIn on rollover with Imagemap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have another image fade in over a defined `<area>` using JavaScript, but I cannot get it to fade or simply even `.show()` the different image. I am using the code below:

```
 // Runs when the DOM has been loaded
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // Check if map exists
     if($('#map')) {
          // Loop through each AREA in the imagemap
          $('#map area').each(function() {

               // Assigning an action to the mouseover event
               $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
                var journey_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('area_', '');
                $('#'+journey_id).fadeIn('medium');
               });

               // Assigning an action to the mouseout event
               $(this).mouseout(function(e) {
                var journey_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('area_', '');
                $('#'+journey_id).hide();
               });

          });
     }
});
```